# How to replace all data inside Object after using .replace(/\D/g,' ') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

My aim to use data inside objects to create divs for the terrain of a game. The .replace() method only seems to work for one div. I can't wrap my head around it.

```
var x = {
  y : { z : '1', z1 : '1', z2 : '1'},
  y1 : { z : '2', z1 : '2', z2 : '2'},
  y2 : { z : '3', z1 : '3', z2 : '3'},
};

var str = JSON.stringify(x);
var str = str
  .replace(/\D/g,' ')
  .replace('1', '<div id=\'grass\'></div>')
  .replace('2', '<div id=\'dirt\'></div>')
  .replace('3', '<div id=\'water\'></div>');
document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable `numsMap` and using the regular expression's `g` global match:

```js
const x = {y : { z : '1', z1 : '1', z2 : '1'},y1 : { z : '2', z1 : '2', z2 : '2'},y2 : { z : '3', z1 : '3', z2 : '3'}};
const numsMap = {
  1: '<div id="grass"></div>',
  2: '<div id="dirt"></div>',
  3: '<div id="water"></div>'
};
const str = JSON.stringify(x)
  .replace(/\D/g, '')
  .replace(/\d/g, n => numsMap[n]);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot cleaner. Any idea how to push <br/> to the object inside the main object? So it will be 3 by 3 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) flag. This will replace more than one occurrence.

```
var str = str
  .replace(/\D/g,' ')
  .replace(/1/g, '<div id=\'grass\'></div>')
  .replace(/2/g, '<div id=\'dirt\'></div>')
  .replace(/3/g, '<div id=\'water\'></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks, had no idea about that. Any suggestion to align the divs in rows as its shown in the x object?

Comment: Create the divs from the object itself in a loop. Matching properties to class names if you have rules to do so.

Comment: Should I use the for/in loop for that? I would need to loop through the y's and then the z's inside the y's loop, right? Also, could I not just use the lastMatch property?